# Unable to connect my dell bh200 blue tooth head set

Tags: 11.04, drivers, bluetooth

Hi I am using dell studio laptop with ubuntu 11.04 and very recently I bought dell bh 200 blue tooth head set but I am not able to connect and pair with my laptop, a quick googling showed few examples for setting it up I amnot able to find ALSA in the sound settings so that Ican listen to the music, how do I set it up, kindly help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in bluez which still shows incomplete in the tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/600137).